# Javascript Drag n Drop files multiple times - add new files to previous ones instead of substituting

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a drag n drop box where I show images preview (for sorting and rotation) and upload them on the server. Everything is ok if I drop one or multiple images the first time. But If I drop new images on top of the existing ones (say I add 2 new images and I already have 3 from previous drop), on the preview I do see all of the images (5 in total), but when I upload to the server only the last 2 get actually uploaded.

Here are portions of the Javascript code I use:

```
form.addEventListener( 'drop', function( e )
    {
    droppedFiles = e.dataTransfer.files; // the files that were dropped
    showFiles( droppedFiles ); // the fx that shows the previews
  });

.....

  var ajaxData = new FormData( form );

  if( droppedFiles ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call( droppedFiles, function( file )
    {
    ajaxData.append( input.getAttribute( 'name' ), file );
    });
  }
```

Comment: You replace droppedFiles value on drop. You should concatenate new file to the dorppedFiles array to keep track on every files

Comment: Hi, just tried to do something like this but does not work. Am I doing it wrong? droppedFiles = droppedFiles.concat(e.dataTransfer.files)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the droppedFiles previous value, use spread operator:

```
droppedFiles = [... droppedFiles, e.dataTransfer.files]; // the files that were dropped
showFiles( droppedFiles ); // the fx that shows the previews
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! However, say I already sorted the first batch of images through jQuery draggable, if I use your approach I am essentially reloading the whole set of images but I loose whatever changes (either changed order of images or rotated them) I made before. How to preserve those changes? Whatever help you can give is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, use push instead, e.dataTransfer.files.forEach(file => droppedFiles.push(file)).

Comment: Thanks but not working. I believe "push" only works on arrays, while what I have is objects. Is there a similar function that deals with objects?

Comment: @AndreaL, Are you saying that droppedFiles is an object? how is it structured?

Comment: From the console log here's the object I get if I upload 3 images: FileList {0: File, 1: File, 2: File, length: 3}

Comment: Here is the error I get from console.log:
Uncaught TypeError: e.dataTransfer.files.forEach is not a function